# Deploy Laravel 4 application without root access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a domain but I don't have root access. I only have access to that /home/bkhan06/public_html folder. Can you please tell me how to deploy application without root access.

Comment: Can you SSH into the server?

Comment: Closing this question is outrageous. You didn't support asker in no way whatsoever. It is a shame to whole SO community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you don't need anything, not even Composer installed on your server:

1 - Copy **every single file** that you have on your development directory to `/home/bkhan06/public_html`. You can use FTP, SCP or RSYNC to do that. And you should end with something like this:

```
/home/bkhan06/public_html/
|    
+ app/
|   |   
|   + commands/
|   |
|   + config/
|   |
|   + ...(many other directories)
|                             
+ bootstrap/
|                             
+ vendor/
|                             
+ composer.json
|                             
+ server.php
|                             
+ ...(other files)
```

2 - Ask your domain administrator to set your domain **document root** to `/home/bkhan06/public_html/public`.

3 - Ask your domain administrator to make `/home/bkhan06/public_html/app/storage` writable by the webserver user (usually www-data or httpd, if it's a Linux)

4 - Test your application (or, first, execute step 5 if you already know which are the missing modules)

5 - Ask your domain administrator to install all missing PHP modules (like php5-mcrypt)

Try to use a program that helps you synchronize your local folder with your server folder, rsync does that for your, but not every FTP client is able to do that. If you don't do that, the next time you need to deploy your app it will take a very long time to copy everything again.

Why you don't need Composer? Because it basically downloads packages and puts them on the vendor directory, so, if you upload this directory to your webserver, you don't need Composer at all.

Comment: Here's an in-depth tutorial for deploying Laravel 4 apps: https://medium.com/laravel-4/3bed5d0e645e

Answer (score -3):

You don't need root access, but you do need an account on the server to be able to install [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). And make other related changes, such as installing php modules, etc.

Comment: Composer is not necessary.